# Hp Quality Center 11.0 connection error

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to connect to HP quality center 11.0 by a windows console application using C# language. 
I added the reference to the dll OTAClient.dll, and added the namespace reference, using TDAPIOLELib;
(Reference to the dll was not happening so i manually registered the dll using the command 
regsvr32 C:\OTAClient.dll ) after which the dll got added.

when i run the program using the below mentioned code i get the error
 Error -> COMException was unhandled.
 The server threw an exception. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80010105 (RPC_E_SERVERFAULT))

Code :

```
TDConnection qctd = new TDConnection();
qctd.InitConnectionEx("http://localhost:8080/qcbin/");
```

I got the error in the second line.
The HP quality center is hosted on a windows web server 2008 r2(64bit OS).

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2):

download the TDClient.exe from add-ins of your qc instance and install it. This will load and register all the required libraries required for runtime on the machine where it is executed.

Answer (score 0):

This must be an exception thrown because your DLL wasn't refered properly. 
If it has been refered try the below code to create the connection object

```
TDConnection qctd = CreateObject("TDApiOle80.TDConnection");
qctd.InitConnectionEx("http://localhost:8080/qcbin/");
```